# What is the difference between the root user and the sudo command in Ubuntu? When should root be used?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

On Ubuntu command prompt you could do `sudo -i` and enter `root` password to login as `root`. My question is, when must you login as this `root` in ubuntu (or Linux)? Is it just to avoid typing `sudo` on commands requiring `root` privilege?

Comment: "and enter root password to login as root" – Note: `sudo` on vanilla Ubuntu asks for *user's* password. One can [change this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71757/108618), but by default there's no password for root at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when must you login as this root in Ubuntu (or Linux)? Is it just to avoid typing `sudo` on commands requiring root privilege?

My interpretation of your questions is:

- Are there scenarios when you must use `sudo -i` because `sudo` is not enough?
- Or `sudo -i` is just to avoid typing `sudo` over and over again, but gives no other advantage?

---

The main advantage of `sudo -i` is it starts a shell. You can then use pipes, redirections etc. as root. Consider:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc conv=noerror bs=32M | pv | gzip -c > /root/image.raw.gz
```

In this case `sudo` affects `dd` only. While you are being prompted for your password, `pv` is already running, your display gets messy. At the same time your shell tells you you have no access to `/root/image.raw.gz`, despite using `sudo`; this is because the redirection (`>`) is performed by the shell which is running without `sudo`.

There are several techniques to circumvent these obstacles. The following list is probably non-exhaustive:

1. Run `sudo true` beforehand and input your password. Your `sudo` will not prompt you again in few minutes, unless it's configured otherwise.
2. Use `sudo tee` like this:

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/sdc conv=noerror bs=32M | pv | gzip -c | sudo tee /root/image.raw.gz > /dev/null
   ```
3. Or run the command inside an extra shell:

   ```
   sudo bash -c 'dd if=/dev/sdc conv=noerror bs=32M | pv | gzip -c > /root/image.raw.gz'
   ```
4. Or run this extra shell and work in it: `sudo bash` or `sudo -i` (both commands are not quite equivalent though).

So you don't really need `-i`. It might not exist, you would still be able to do things as root.

---

Another advantage may be that `sudo -i` runs a shell that sources the root's files (like `.profile`), while `sudo bash` or `sudo bash -l` use the invoking user's files. I can imagine one may have an environment defined for root, tailored to do administrative tasks. In this case `sudo -i` is useful.

---

Dangers of working in a shell running with root privileges are covered by other answers. I won't repeat them.

Comment: Nitpicking: `pv` will never be started because the shell will have to do the redirection before starting `pv`.

Comment: @kasperd You're right, thank you. Example changed to let it actually run `pv`.

Answer (score 5):

#### Unless there is a good reason for you to use `root` regularly—and I can’t think of one—`sudo` is the better alternative to save you from yourself and provide basic system hardening to your OS install.

`root` is a historic artifact of Unix/Linux systems. Many systems have a `root` user set as default—such as RedHat and CentOS—but to the best of my knowledge, Ubuntu specifically forces you by default to use a non-`root` user to do `sudo`/`root` required things. `sudo` was born out of the need to prevent `root` being such a known and vulnerable target user and delegate `root` privileges to other users on the system in a controlled and focused way. As explained in “[Sudo in a Nutshell](https://www.sudo.ws/intro.html)”:

> Sudo (su "do") allows a system administrator to give certain users (or groups of users) the ability to run some (or all) commands as root while logging all commands and arguments. Sudo operates on a per-command basis, it is not a replacement for the shell. Its features include:
>
> - The ability to restrict what commands a user may run on a per-host basis.
> - Sudo does copious logging of each command, providing a clear audit trail of who did what. When used in tandem with syslogd, the system log daemon, sudo can log all commands to a central host (as well as on the local host). At CU, all admins use sudo in lieu of a root shell to take advantage of this logging.
> - Sudo uses timestamp files to implement a "ticketing" system. When a user invokes sudo and enters their password, they are granted a ticket for 5 minutes (this timeout is configurable at compile-time). Each subsequent sudo command updates the ticket for another 5 minutes. This avoids the problem of leaving a root shell where others can physically get to your keyboard. There is also an easy way for a user to remove their ticket file, useful for placing in a .logout file.
> - Sudo's configuration file, the **sudoers** file, is setup in such a way that the same sudoers file may be used on many machines. This allows for central administration while keeping the flexibility to define a user's privileges on a per-host basis. Please see the samples sudoers file below for a real-world example.

On a practical level, using `sudo` forces the end user to think about what they are doing. If I were to simply type `rm -rf *` as `root` the command would work… **But 99% of the time anything anyone does on a Unix/Linux system does not need `root` privileges.** So having unlimited power as `root` all the time is silly at best, risky at worst.

Also, since `root` is a known login, a lot of system administrators disable the `root` account login—and lock it down—by default and assign equivalent rights via `sudo` to another user. **Believe it or not simply disabling `root` is one of the quickest, simplest and best ways to provide basic security to a system from SSH login attempt attacks.** Just create a new user—something like `cooldude`—and then give that user `sudo` rights and your system is already on a solid footing.

The reason being is the gajillion “script kiddies” and off-the-shelf system penetration tools target `root` access via (seemingly) endless SSH login attempts straight out of the box. These off-the-shelf system penetration tools are generic and brainless tools at best. You leave `root` active with a simple password and you are waiting for a problem to happen. But by simply giving admin rights to someone like `cooldude` all of those scripts are now ineffective. Yes, of course if someone knows your `root` equivalent is `cooldude` they can target that… But 99.9999% of the time, an attacker won’t be ambitious enough to delve that deep.

Switch into `root` at your own risk. I do professional Linux system administration work and have not touched `root` past an initial install stage for the past 20 years.

Comment: Ubuntu absolutely allows you to lg in as root - just give the root user a password and you are all set.

Answer (score 1):

One should not login as the root user, unless there is a very specific reason to do so.  When logged in as root, you have the ability to, at worst, destroy the entire system.  Some UNIX/Linux systems default to denying the root user login privileges to prevent such an occurrence.  Forcing a user to login as a standard user and use `sudo` to run elevated commands is a safety and security measure.

Im sure many people on SU and other IT related StackExchange sites (including me) have made the mistake of logging in as root (or Administrator on Windows) and forgot.  Then they did something they *very* much did not want to do.

Comment: There's a fun old story about that kind of thing.... http://www.lug.wsu.edu/node/414

Comment: My impression is the questions can be rephrased as "what is the purpose of `sudo -i`? is it just to avoid typing `sudo` over and over again?". You didn't answer these directly and your implicit answer seems to be "the purpose is to circumvent some systems' denying behavior". Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

sudo -i is simply 1 way of getting an interactive session as root.  (There are a number of other ways available from Ubuntu, including sudo /bin/bash, and enabling a root password and logging in as root).

The idea behind this all is "least privilege". For most day-to-day things (web browsing, photo editing, office documents etc) you don't need to get into the internals of the system.    Running as a normal user prevents you from doing some stupid things on your system, and is a best practice.

Occasionally you will need to do something which requires more privileges - for example format a disk or install software which is shared among users - in these cases you would use root.   If its a single command, using sudo is adequate, but often there are a number of related tasks to do, in which case using sudo gets irritating real fast.

Separating administration usage from regular user access can prevent bad programs from doing bad damage - like erasing the entire system - and is a good precaution - but it really comes into its own when a device is shared between multiple users.

sudo / root access is analogous to "run as administrator" on a Windows box - and provides similar benefits and frustrations.  I do note that sudo can be used not only to get root access, but alternatively to get access to other non-root users.    There is also controls and permissions (generally set up in /etc/sudoers or /etc/sudoers.d ) which can allow certain users to only run certain things with elevated privileges and/or allow access without an additional password for some users.